# Changing minSdkVersion from 15 to 16

Tags: android

When I changed my minSdkVersion then I am getting this error:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class TextView

Eariler it was working fine before I have made the changes.

**Here is my style :**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/greyDark</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/off_white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/pink</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:transition/move</item>

    </style>
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/pink</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="android:height">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

I guess there is something wrong with the parent property of a style.

Comment: Change again misSDKVersion and check is it working or not?

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Not working I have already checked couple of times Pratik answer didn't helped me since I have already appcompact version 24.2.1

Comment: I am asking that in whatever minSDKVersion it was working check with that one, if it is not working for that then please add your xml file for the error.

Comment: wait a min I got this look, I have appcompact version 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' but all the style I am using has simple,v11,v14,v17 so does it matter because earlier it didn't showed any error

Comment: @ReadyAndroid I said na it is working for minsdkVersion 15 I tested read my question

Comment: @ReadyAndroid but I in API 15 I can't use font family for android

Comment: Can you add your xml layout code

Comment: @ReadyAndroid When I have revert back to minsdkVersions 15 then I am getting the same thing......This changing sdkVersions have caused me a serious problem I am getting the same error for previous build in which it was working fine pls help now

Comment: @ReadyAndroid android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class TextView this is the same error

Comment: So man, issue is not with your minSDKVersion, issue is related to your style code. I already asked for the xml code file to add in you question so we can easily find out the line of source code where is the problem. Please add your xml lines of code to your question.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Nope I made a backup of my code loaded that code working fine again for api level 16 but the main task is to add font family here now I hope there will be no error . I'll inform you......xml is perfect nothing wrong in xml I wish I could share my code with you so that you could see there is no error in my code

Comment: I doesn't mean with your code error, may be the style you are using for the textview that is creating issue at the time of code compiling.

Comment: Found the error as soon as I add this <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item> my app gets crashed

Comment: As like you had written <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item> for the AppTheme.Dark in style. Check that sans-serif-light font exists in your assests or not. Check also after removing of both these lines.

Comment: assests ? what ? do I have to add assests for font family???

Comment: Yes, as you are using sans-serif-light a font family so it should be located in your code. And the best place to put font family in code is assets folder.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Okay how and where do I find a file to download these fonts can you give me the link

Comment: First remove these lines of code from your style <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item> <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item> then check is it working or not. First of all we have to identify this issue is related to font family or something else. Then I will provide you answer for how to apply font family.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Okay Working but I have to replace all the values folder from backup to my current app folder

Comment: You can do that but just make sure if you don't have any font family in assets folder till that you can't use their names as you are doing now

Comment: You can download font family from https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/sans%20serif | 
http://www.1001fonts.com/sans-serif-fonts.html | 
https://cooltext.com/Fonts-Sans-Serif | Or follow https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/custom-font-style-android/ to apply font family

Comment: @ReadyAndroid come to discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132757/discussion-between-samh67-and-ready-android).

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Now What do I do???

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing your version then also change the support library.You have to change the support lib like for e.g.for api 23 you have to chnage the appcompact library version to 23.
Hope this help.:)

Comment: Nopes my appcompact library version is : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

Comment: change the app theme

Comment: Ok but what's the change ?

Comment: change the app theme to light

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on 3.0+ devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class TextView getting this again didnt helped

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity Your new resource is causing this

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

to

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with your font family which you are using in style. May be sans-serif-light font is not available in your assests>>fonts folder. So check with this how to use custom fonts in android.

Here are the steps to follow:

**Android Studio:**

Step1: Adding font family files to app

A) Go to the (project folder)

B) Then app>src>main

C) Create folder 'assets>fonts' into the main folder.

D) Put your 'abc.ttf' or 'abc.otf' font file into the fonts folder.

Step 2:
Now Create attrs.xml under res folder if it's not exists and add declare-styleable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="Font">
<attr name="typeface">
<enum name="FuturaLT" value="0" />
<enum name="FuturaLT_Heavy" value="1" />
<enum name="FuturaLT_Light" value="2" />
</attr>
</declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

//Here FuturaLT/FuturaLT_Heavy/FuturaLT_Light are file names

**Note:** – enum name should be font type name with underscore(_) uses, it will be easy for you to understand font family usage in your native code. No special character or other letter, otherwise you will got error in gen folder for same attribute id.

Step 3: Create your custom view(Button, TextView, EditText) class:-

```
package com.myapp.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.myapp.R;

public class CustomTextView extends TextView  {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        try {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Font);
            int font = a.getInt(R.styleable.Font_typeface, 0);
            a.recycle();
            String str;
            switch (font) {
                case 1:
                    str = "fonts/FuturaLT.otf";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    str = "fonts/FuturaLT_Heavy.otf";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    str = "fonts/FuturaLT_Light.otf";
                    break;
                default:
                    str = "fonts/FuturaLT.otf";
                    break;
            }

            setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance(getContext()).loadFont(str));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void internalInit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    }
}
```

Step 4: Add FontManager.java support class

```
package com.myapp.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FontManager {
    private Map<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
    private static FontManager instance = null;
    private Context mContext;

    private FontManager(Context mContext2) {
        mContext = mContext2;
    }

    public synchronized static FontManager getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FontManager(mContext);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Typeface loadFont(String font) {
        if (false == fontCache.containsKey(font)) {
            fontCache.put(font, Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), font));
        }
        return fontCache.get(font);
    }
}
```

Step 5: Usage in XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.myapp.views.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time_slot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:typeface="FuturaLT" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use in java code directly:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FuturaLT.ttf");
tvText.setTypeface(tf);
```

**Note:-** If you don't use here FontManager to apply typeface and directly use
then you are not able to see your views in graphics preview.

Comment: Pls see discussion I have asked something there